# Load Data from EXCEL/ CSV to MYSQL using query?

Tags: mysql, excel, load, loaddata

I am trying to load data from Excel/ CSV file in MYSQL DB?
What is wrong with this code??

```
LOAD DATA INFILE "D:/MY_SQL_Practice/Sales_Data.csv" INTO TABLE sales_data 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
ignore 1 rows;
```

Comment: What makes you think there is something wrong with it? (works fine for me)

Comment: You should add the table definition and the first few lines of the csv file as text to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Like describe on mysql reference, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html
The example used only ' and never " on syntax :
LOAD DATA INFILE **'/tmp/jokes.txt'** INTO TABLE jokes
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ''
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n%%\n' (joke);

Can you try this syntax ? replace " by ':

LOAD DATA INFILE 'D:/MY_SQL_Practice/Sales_Data.csv' INTO TABLE sales_data 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
ignore 1 rows;